# Get String If Found "string" In The List

Tags: c#, list

I Want To Get The Full **string** If I Founded **char** In The List

My Code :

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>(); 
// My List Contains : 1-Cat , 2-Dog , 3-Wolf , 4-Mouse
string text = "";
if (mylist.contains("3")) 
{
    text = ...//Get The Line That The "3" Is Founded In It
    // In This Case text must be : 3-Wolf
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: myList.First(p => p == "3")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this code

```
var text = mylist.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("3"));
// note: text will be **null** if not found in the list
```

Comment: your solution is good but contains some typo error Contains"3" to Contains("3") or rather Contains('3') since OP asks for `char`.

Comment: Thankyou Very Much! , It Works :)

Comment: @Ian: thanks for pointing out the typo. `Contains("3")` is more close to OP's sample code

Comment: Seems to me that `var text = mylist.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("3")) ?? string.Empty;` is more suitable to the original question?

Comment: @UweKeim: agreed with you that it's closer to OP's sample code, but I prefer to keep it `null` if `not found` rather than setting it to empty string

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the service:

```
        List<string> mylist = new List<string>() { "1-Cat", "2-Dog", "3-Wolf", "4-Mouse" };
        // My List Contains : 1-Cat , 2-Dog , 3-Wolf , 4-Mouse
        string text = "";
        text = mylist.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains('3')); // text will be 3-Wolf. In case there is no strings in the list that contains 3 text will be null.

        // If you want do some other things if the list contains "3" you can do the following:
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            // Do your stuff here
        }
```